# Requiring compiled ES6 Modules from dist

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have two questions.

**Question #1**

I'm writing npm package on ES6 and have following package.json:

```
{
   "name": "mypackage",
   "bin": {
       "mybin": "dist/bin/mybin.js"
   },
   "dependencies": [...],
   "devDependencies": [...],
   "directories": {
       "lib": "dist"
   },
   "main": "dist/index.js",
   "scripts": {
       "compile": "./node_modules/.bin/babel ./src --optional runtime --presets es2015,stage-0 -d ./dist",
       "prepublish": "npm run compile"
   }
}
```

Everything is compiled successfully every time.
However, I can include:

```
var mypackage = require('mypackage');
```

But I'm not able to include subfolder with the same starting path:

```
var constants = require('mypackage/core/constants');
```

Of course `constants.js` has following full path `mypackage/dist/core/constants.js`

But I would like to include it without `dist` part..
For now to include constants I should write like this:

```
var constants = require('mypackage/dist/core/constants');
```

Which doesn't make a lot of sense.

I don't like approach when I should use `NODE_PATH` to solve this issue.
I need solution without making users extra-efforts to include `dist` folder contents.
At least users should not rely to compilation/publishing folders structure, they should not even know anything about this.

**Question #2**

How can I compile all the `.es6` files to `dist` and then copy all the other files except compiled from `src` to `dist`?
For example, I have different templates, assets, etc.
I would like structure of `dist` to be exactly the same including all the files as in `src` but `.es6` compiled to `.js`.

I know obvious solution to copy entire `src` to `dist` and then compile everything from `dist` to `dist`, but it doesn't look like a smart way for me.

On the other hand, I wouldn't like to specify every single asset/image/template to copy to `dist` folder.

May be there's gulp plugin to make exact copy from folder to folder but excluding all the files with given extension (or regexp)?

**Update #1**

@molda

I have also structure inside:

```
     -- src/modules
     ---- module1
     -------- static
     ---- module2
     -------- static
```

So keeping all the static files in src/static isn't solution

Comment: You could place all static files in `./src/statics` and first copy content of this folder to root folder of your package `./` to avoid having `./dist` folder (but you need to make sure you don't overwrite any file you already have in `./`) and then simply compile es6 files to `./` instead of `./dist`. Also there's definitely a *gulp way* to do this.

Comment: for the first question, you can export constants from index.js and `export default` the default content, so that they can just `import mypackage, { constatnts } from mypacakage`